# Adding references in Single File ASP.NET Web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am facing a trouble in adding reference to libraries in my Application which contains single-file web form.

I have an onClick event handler and I want to add a reference of WebClient class which I am unable to do. Following is the code for my click event handler:

```
<script runat="server">
 protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "http://anydomain.net/REST/message_send.aspx?API_KEY=anykey&name=" + name_box.Text + "&email=" + email_box.Text + "&website=" + website_box.Text + "&message=" + msg_box.Text + "";

            var client = new WebClient();

            string reply = client.DownloadString(url);

            msg_lbl.Text = "Request submitted. Our representative will get back to you soon.";
            msg_lbl.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very general description, I have no idea what does it mean "unable" in this case. So I have only a guess: have you added `using System.Net;` directive?

Or you can specify a full name in your code:

`System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();`